# Can't get Google Maps to initialize iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, sdk

This issue just doesn't make sense. I keep getting this:

```
[GMSMapView animateToCameraPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x93864f0
```

The error seems to be coming from my attempts at initialization, from both init methods and class methods. The code causing the problem is this:

```
self.myMapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
```

It seems to me that there is something wrong with Google's code, because I am not calling the method, Google's code seems to be. Is there something I'm missing or do I have to wait for Google to fix this bug? Perhaps an older version will work?

Comment: Can you add whole code?

Comment: The issue seems to be the initialization process. Calling GMSMapView's initWithFrame: causes this same exact error. I'm dumbfounded quite frankly... I don't think dumping my code will help as I have isolated the problem. I have also verified that GMSMapView+Animations.h is being imported correctly. I am able to use methods from it (albeit on uninitialized instances, since I can't get that part to work).

Answer (score 0):

Check this method:

```
- (void) moveCameraToPosition:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) position
{

    GMSCameraUpdate *camera = [GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:position];
    [_mapView animateWithCameraUpdate:camera];


}
```

This is working fine for me.